# How to send message from Chrome extension to website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I've created a Chrome extension with the following code:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "My Chrome extension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "scripts/background.js"
    ]
  },
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
      "http://*.mywebsite.com/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

So, I can [send message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) from my website to Chrome extension:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(EXT_ID, {
  data: 'ping'
});
```

And [handle the message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessageExternal) from background.js like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log(message.data);
});
```

But how can I send a message from Chrome extension to my website? [Chrome's document](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) do not say anything about this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) perhaps? or a [customEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) on window

Comment: @JaromandaX It works. Thank you!